# how to build a json file from a template in inserting values

Tags: json

example of a json (template) file:

```
{
  "AlarmName": "{{$alarm_name}}",
  "AlarmDescription": "{{$alarm_descr}}",
  "MetricName": "{{$alarm_metric}}",
  "Namespace": "{{$alarm_namespace}}",
  "AlarmActions": "{{$alarm_actions}}"
}
```

I want to create a template that permits me to create json files with different values.

Any suggestions?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Any template engine will help you with this. Freemarker, mustache, Thymeleaf, velocity is just a small list for Java developers to choose from.